# Help with regexp in <Files> tag of .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, regular-expressions

For poorly configured Apache servers you can have to do something like this to deny access to the .htaccess file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

I would like to deny access to all system files (.* - any file that it's filename starts with a dot). I know it's possible with FilesMatch...

Something like this (but working):

```
<FilesMatch .*>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.(.*)$">
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

FilesMatch uses a regex there.

Comment: just ... do not forget the closing `"` :)

Comment: @LazyOne: right, fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Goodnight,
If I want to block access to domain/path/?xxxx (xxxx is variable), but allow access to domain/path/, how should I write it in my .htaccess?